# Min-width and max-width not working on div and image

Tags: css, width

I am trying to add a min and max width to the className "tile" however what I am using at the moment in my CSS isn't working. Once my screen size goes below 480px it jumps from this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

The height stays the same however it doesn't gradually change width when resizing the screen.

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 .tile {
    position: relative;
    height: 192px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    width: 100%;
}
.tile-image {
    height: 192px;
    margin-left: 24px;
    object-fit: cover;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 4px;
    max-width: 432px;
    min-width: 272px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.tile-gradient {
    background-blend-mode: darken;
    background-image: linear-gradient(228deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.36));
    height: 192px;
    object-fit: cover;
    border-radius: 4px;
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 24px;
    margin-right: 24px;
    max-width: 432px;
    min-width: 272px;
 }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 481px) {
.tile {
    position: relative;
    width: 432px;
    height: 192px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
}
.tile-image {
    width: 432px;
    height: 192px;
    margin-left: 24px;
    object-fit: cover;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 4px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.tile-gradient {
    background-blend-mode: darken;
    background-image: linear-gradient(228deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.36));
    width: 432px;
    height: 192px;
    object-fit: cover;
    border-radius: 4px;
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 24px;
    margin-right: 24px;
 }
}
```

```html
<div className="tile">
  <div className="image">
    <div className="tile-gradient"></div>
    <img className={`tile-image ${!post.availability && "is-available"} `} src={post.img} alt=""/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any idea on how to fix this and make it responsive would be great so it does not jump from once size to the other automatically. Thank you in advance, please ask if any other information is required.

Comment: Maybe this article may help you [https://ishadeed.com/article/min-max-css/](https://ishadeed.com/article/min-max-css/)

Comment: Max-width and min-width needs to add directly to the image. try: .tile-image img { ... }

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you're not using a screen width percentage to reduce the width of `tile` element. It directly change from `100%` width to a specific `432px` as you set it inside your `@media screen and (min-width: 481px)` query. Try to avoid specific pixel width and adjust it with percentage. Something like

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 .tile {
    position: relative;
    height: 192px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    width: 100%;
}
}

@media screen and (min-width: 481px) {
.tile {
    position: relative;
    width: 80%; // change this with the desired width of the element. Avoid using px
    height: 192px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
}
}
```

A gradual change of width happens when resizing the screen if you're using percentages instead of specific pixels.